# add record and then repopulate a select field with updated array AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-4

Situation: Laravel 4.2 
I have a form with a select box

```
{{ Form::select('NameCustomary', $ent) }}
```

with pre-populated persons names.
In the controller:

```
$ent = array('' => 'Choose existing person') + Entity::orderBy('NameCustomary','asc')->lists('NameCustomary', 'id');
```

What I need:
If a person (model name is Entity) is not on the list, I wish to

- add a new Entity and then repopulate the select with updated $ent.
- if possible, I wish to set the select box on the newly added name, to save trouble to the user. Additional info: the select box is working on select2 script.

I tried several times, but I have difficulties with mastering AJAX and JQuery and failed to put the mechanism together.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution. It is crude, but it works as desired.

FIRST, after reading [this tutorial](http://blog.igeek.info/2013/using-ajax-in-laravel/)
I managed to post a form using AJAX
Important note: 
the form which uses AJAX must be placed OUTSIDE of the form you want to modify! I used a modal - this way the AJAX form can be triggered up with a button present within the original form.

TWO,
in the controler method I added new entity to database and also inculded this response array:

```
        $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'msg' => 'Option created successfully',
        'new_entity_id' => '<input class="" name="NameCustomary" type="hidden" value="'.$LastInsertId.'" id="NameCustomary">',
        'new_entity' => Input::get( 'NameCustomary' )
    );

    return Response::json( $response );
```

THIRD, 
I added a JS to replace content of the original form. Note the value of new_entity_id in the above array. My original problem was only my misconception - I am a noob. I only needed a way to populate the original form. I don't need to use a select box as I have already chose a newly created value.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('#form-quick-entity').on('submit', function(){ 

   // ajax post method to pass form data to the 
    $.post(
        $(this).prop('action'),        {
            "_token": $( this ).find( 'input[name=_token]' ).val(),
            "option_name": $( '#kv_option_name' ).val(),
            "option_value": $( '#kv_option_value' ).val(),
            "NameCustomary": $( this ).find( 'input[name=NameCustomary]' ).val(),
            "itemtype_id": $( this ).find( 'input[name=itemtype_id]' ).val()
        },
        function(data){
            //response after the process.
            $('#experiment_update2').text(data.msg); 
            $('#entity_place').replaceWith(data.new_entity_id); 
            $('#entity_name').text(data.new_entity); 
            $('#entity_name').addClass('but- block padding csh_11 margins'); 
            $('#entity_name').removeClass('hidden'); 
            $('#modal_quick_add_entity').modal('hide');
        },
        'json'
    ); 

    return false;
});
```

});

Note the last command in the above JS: it is the command to close down the modal. It it is triggered by the very same click which send the form to the controller method. It happens after the original form is replaced and the modal is no longer necessary -

DONE.

If you know a better solution or have a way to improve on the above code, please do it!